# sql server campo decimal a formato de fecha

Tags: sql-server

Hola tengo una tabla [ejemplo] que posee un campo `[fechaalta] decimal (8,0) null`

```
20201212
20191010
19990415
19971103
20080314
20150915
19971103
20190926
19000101
```

y lo quiero mostrar en un `select` con el siguiente formato:

```
12/12/2020
10/10/2019
15/04/1999
.
.
.
01/01/1900
```

Necesito ayuda muchas Gracias.

Comment: Lo queres mostrar en un select donde? porque en ese caso, el problema no seria de sql server... seria de donde lo mostras... o te referis en una consulta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si bien de entrada, revisaría el diseño (no es común manejar fechas como un tipo de dato que no sea fecha), lo que puedes hacer es utilizar las funciones de conversión y manejo de cadenas en SQL Server.
Primero, conviertes de decimal a string utilizando la función Convert...
Y luego tomas el resultado y recuperas las partes relevantes con la función substring.
Algo como lo siguiente (a modo de ejemplo, pongo una variable)...

```
declare @fechaalta decimal;
select @fechaalta = 20201217;
select SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, @fechaalta),7,2) +'/'+ SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, @fechaalta),5,2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, @fechaalta),1,4) as fecha
```

Lo anterior te dará el siguiente resultado:

```
17/12/2020
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 2):

Convierte a fecha y luego utiliza [FORMAT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

**LA SOLUCIÓN:**

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME,convert(CHAR(8),20201212)),'dd/MM/yyyy') as Fecha
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME,convert(CHAR(8),20191010 )),'dd/MM/yyyy') as Fecha
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME,convert(CHAR(8),19990415 )),'dd/MM/yyyy') as Fecha
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]